# Best programming language

Tags: statistics, career, programming

I have a masters in pure statistics. I have no knowledge of any programming language. Which is the best programming language that I should learn about and will help enhance my career in data analysis.

I only have a theoretical knowledge of concepts. Kindly suggest a skill that I should develop in order to become a data analyst.

Comment: An [Introduction to Machine Learning with Python](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920030515.do) would complement your theoretical knowledge. If you want to do more production work, pick up a copy of [Sedgwick](https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/home/) or [Skiena](http://www.algorist.com/). The skill you need right now is probably _practice_. Welcome to the site and good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to become a data analyst then R is the best language for you. It is purely made for statistical analysis. It is a free software, so you can install it in your system without any hassle. You can find about it here-

https://www.r-project.org/about.html

It has nearly 10,000 packages which you can use as per your requirement. You can find many free tutorials for it as well.

Answer (score 0):

There are many options, and the choice is driven by the domain at hand.

That been said, without any prior knowledge or preferences, I think that the default choice is **python**. Python has a strong ecosystem and many open-source libraries you can leverage.

There are considerations for other options, like **Scala/Java** as it has a strong Machine Learning community as well as big-data technologies (For example - Apache Spark, Apache Kafka). While it's arguable how well python is suited for building large scale applications, it becomes much simpler with Java world.

In each of these choices, you can still use **R** as you can execute R code from within Java/Python (for example using Spark).